# Are there other idioms that mean "do someone the favor of x"

Tags: idiom-request

I wrote the following, but I find it a bit unnatural, I can't really think of many other ways to say this.

> If you choose to ask me questions about my work instead of questions
>   about my personal life, I **will indulge you in** giving you an
>   interview.

Is there a better and more simple, natural way of saying this? Any slang you can think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is:

> If you ask me questions about my work rather than questions about my personal life, I will be happy to give you an interview.

Note, I tweaked the first part of the sentence as well to make it sound more natural to me. Another way to say it would be:

> So long as you stick to questions about my work, and not questions about my personal life, I will be happy to give you an interview.

Answer (score 0):

If you rather ask me questions about my work instead of questions about my personal life, I can **fix you up** with an interview.

**Definition**: *If you fix someone up with something they need, you provide it for them.*

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to drop the first part of the sentence and focus only on what you want, also using a bit of parallelism:

> If you indulge me by only asking me about my work, I will indulge you by giving you an interview.

Note that I've also changed the preposition from *in* to *by*.

---

If you actually want *slang*, then something like this could work:

> Do me a solid and ask only about my work, and I'll do you a solid and give you an interview.

[*Do me a solid*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/do_someone_a_solid) is slang which means *do me a favour*. (It seems more common in US English.)